# AWS ACL getting real ip behind third party CDN

Tags: amazon-web-services, cdn

We're using third parties CDN WAF from 3 suppliers.
I would like to add another layer of protection to the ELB in AWS. How can i make sure the AWS ACLs is getting the real user IP instead of taking action on the IP from third parties CDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original IP will be in the `X-Forwarded-For:` HTTP header. Be aware that the ELB will add the CDN IP to this header as well.

Hope that helps :)